# Tomcat - Deployed application sets root privileges

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, tomcat7

I've installed Fedora on my server and I've added Tomcat7 and JDK7. When I deploy my application (ROOT.war) it has root privileges on linux.

Firstly, I thought that this is because the Tomcat folder had root privileges - I've changed that. All files in Tomcat folder, had tomcat:tomcat privileges, also ROOT.war.

Unfortunatelly, after redeploy, ROOT folder had root privileges again.

Comment: This is likely because the tomcat process is running as root

Comment: Ok, bot what should i change, to run process as tomcat, not root ?

Comment: That depends on how you're starting Tomcat.

Comment: i've changed user to tomcat, and starting /etc/init.d/tomcat start

Comment: Ok, i had to do something wrong - now it's working

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that the tomcat process is not running in root, just do:

`ps -fea|grep tomcat`

and you will see some like that:

```
yourusername  6125     1  0 May09 ?        00:55:53 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/yourusername/programas/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/conf/logging.properties -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/yourusername/programas/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/endorsed -classpath /home/yourusername/programas/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/yourusername/programas/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/home/yourusername/programas/apache-tomcat-7.0.32 -Dcatalina.home=/home/yourusername/programas/apache-tomcat-7.0.32 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/yourusername/programas/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Where "yourusername" maybe root, if that the case, you will now why is writing the folder with root permissions,

Regards,